# How to get string value of selector that was used $('*selector*).on(...) in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

Is there a way to get a string value of selector, that was used to search elements?

[This property](https://api.jquery.com/selector/) is now deprecated in 3.0 and higher versions of jQuery.

I am trying to apply that to the code below to replace `.siblings('.upper-link')` with `.siblings(*selector*)`.

```
$('.upper-link').on('mouseover', function (e) {
                $(e.currentTarget)
                    .addClass('make-wider')
                    .siblings('.upper-link')
                    .addClass('make-thinner');
            });
```

Thank you.

Comment: Why would you need this? I can't think of a scenario where you'd know the selector before runtime, but not at runtime. It's likely there's a more suitable method to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 0):

Even though I mostly agree with Rory's comment: "Why would you need this?" it can be achieved, although it's an odd one, since you need to "know" the *selector* somehow anyway.
You could, for instance add a data-attribute like so:

```
<div class='upper-link' data-sibling-type='.my-selector'>
```

and use that "sibling-type" as a *selector*, something along the lines of this (not tested):

```
$('.upper-link').on('mouseover', function (e) {
   let childSelector = $(e).data('sibling-type');     
    $(e.currentTarget)
        .addClass('make-wider')
        .siblings(childSelector)
            .addClass('make-thinner');
});
```

Still remaining: Why would you need this?